# Store output of command into the array

Tags: scripts

This is command: `pdc status -a 2>&1 | grep 'okay'` It gives the following output

```
[okay     ]: you are currently listening: 33
[okay     ]: you are currently listening: 22
[okay     ]: you are currently listening: 11
```

I have written this command in shell scrip file. But I want to store the output of this command into the array for some processing on each of the index value in the array.

How can I store the output of this command into the array?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you just want the numbers at the end of each line:

```
numbers=( $(pdc ... | grep -oP 'okay.+?\K\d+$') )
```

If you want to store each line into the array

```
mapfile -t lines < <(pdc ...)
```

To retrieve the data from the arrays:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#numbers[@]}; i++ )); do echo ${numbers[i]}; done
echo
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}"
```

```
33
22
11

[okay   ]: you are currently listening: 33
[okay   ]: you are currently listening: 22
[okay   ]: you are currently listening: 11
```

Comment: Syntax error: redirection unexpected, when I use `mapfile -t array < <(grep.....)`

Comment: Are you using bash or some other shell?

Answer (score 21):

First of all, you don't necessarily need the array, to process the output line by line you can do:

```
pdc status -a 2>&1 | grep 'okay' | while read line; do somecommand "$line"; done
```

If you do need the array, Glenn Jackman [already gave](https://askubuntu.com/a/439038/85695) you the best way to do it but here's another approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(pdc status -a 2>&1 | grep 'okay'))
```

**Explanation:**

- `$IFS=$'\n'` : `$IFS` is bash's [input field separator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html), setting it to the newline character only (`\n`) ensures that your output lines won't be split on whitespace so that you can save each line as a separate array element. Without this, each *word* of your command's output would be a different element.

  Depending on what you want to do, it might be a good idea to save the old value of `$IFS` and restore it after the array is read:

  ```
  oldifs="$IFS"
  IFS=$'\n'
  array=($(echo -e "foo bar\nbaz bar"))
  IFS="$oldifs"
  ```
- `$(command)` : This is called [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and allows you to save the output of a command in a variable. There are two ways of doing this:

  ```
  var=$(command)
  ```

  and

  ```
  var=`command`
  ```

  Of the two, the `$()` is better because:

  - It can deal with nested commands:

    ```
    var=$(command1 $(command 2))
    ```

    For example `var=$(cat $(find ~/))`
  - It has far fewer issues with quoting and results in cleaner syntax. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/22222) for more.

Answer (score 12):

Yet another more intuitive way using `readarray` builtin (see `help -m readarray`):

```
readarray -t array <<< "$(pdc status -a 2>&1 | grep 'okay')"
```

Next, to print an array element, let say second element, you can use:

```
echo "${array[1]}"
```

To print all array elements on separate lines, you can use:

```
printf -- "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: readarray -t "[array]" <<< "$([command])"